# Pip error, OSError Errno 22 invalid argument

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

When searching for or install packages with pip, I get the following error:

```
pip3 search validate
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument'))': /pypi
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 289, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 791, in __init__
    self.getpeername()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more times]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 640, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 287, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 45, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 62, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 775, in request
    headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 522, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')))
```

Pip version: pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
Python version: 3.6.3
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13

I've tried reinstalling python and pip. I don't believe I'm using any proxies, and it's probably not firewall (I can ping/dig pypi.python.org).

After some additional digging, running `curl pypi.python.org` emits the same error: `curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument`.

Comment: It looks like it might be a temporary issue with PyPI (which is undergoing a lot of transition at the moment).

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm only experiencing this issue on one of my machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, this was an issue with IPv6 on macOS High Sierra. To resolve, open your network preferences, select Wi-Fi from the list, and click "Advanced...". Click on the TCP/IP tab, then change Configure IPv6 to Link-local only.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Python 2.7 and pip on mac osx 10.13.4. Above solution doesn't seem to resolve the issue, any other alternatives?